# How to properly handle multiple asynchronous requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Does anyone know some good resources/books where I can find out how to handle multiple async requests?

Let's consider code below:

```
Payment.createToken = function(data) {
    var data = data;

    apiCall("POST", "api/createToken", data, function(success, response) {
        if (success) {
            data.token = response.id;

            // If there's coupon code passed in data object, check it's validity, else send payment request
            if (data.coupon) {
                // Check if coupon is valid
                Payment.verifyCoupon(data);
            } else {
                // Send payment request
                Payment.chargePlan(data);
            }
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
};

Payment.verifyCoupon = function(data) {
    var data = data;

    apiCall("POST", "/api/checkCoupon", data, function(success, response) {
        if (success) {
            Payment.chargePlan(data);
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
};

Payment.chargePlan = function(data) {
    apiCall("POST", "/api/chargePlan", data, function(success, response) {
        if (success) {
            Payment.changeUserType(data);
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
};

Payment.changeUserType = function(data, response) {
    apiCall("PUT", "api/users/", data, function(success, response) {
        if (success) {
            // User type changed successfully
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
};
```

As you can see, it's long, 4 steps flow. How should I properly handle errors etc.? Let's take into account that those calls should be reusable as much as possible.

Comment: Use [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this library](https://github.com/caolan/async) with some success.  It helps reduce the clutter and gives you the option to run various processes in order or simultaneously (keeping track of when all are actually done).

And it takes references to optional error handling callbacks if you need to know if something went wrong.

I realize it's not the exact answer you're looking for, but it may be helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I usually create a queue of async operations to undertake and run them in series, calling the next one only if previous succeeds, if it - doesn't then the final callback is called directly with the error as first argument.